# Gradient Vector of Homogeneous Functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I've been given the definition $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is homogeneous of degree k if $f(\lambda x)=\lambda^kf(x)$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n, \lambda>0$ 
and asked to show $<\nabla f(x),x>=kf(x)$.
For differentiable $f$ this seems to follow pretty trivially and I believe it also holds when we only assume continuity of $f$.

However, as far as I can tell $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ s.t $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$, $f(0,0)=1$ satisifies the homogeneity condition but does not even have well defined gradient function at $0$ since:
$$lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}=lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2-1}{x}$$
which does not converge.

Is this counter-example correct or am I mistaken? Additionally if not would changing the condition to $f(\lambda x)=\lambda^kf(x)$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n, \lambda\geq0$ be sufficient to prove the result.

Comment: Your example of $f$ does not satisfy the homogeneity condition of degree 2 for $x=0$ and $\lambda \neq 1$.

Comment: Ahh of course, thank you very much